# How to add ListView items where a CheckBox is selected to separate ArrayList?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-checkbox

I am developing an app in which I want to display all the installed applications in a ListView.
I succeeded in doing so. Each item in my ListView contains an application name and a CheckBox. I want that whenever a user presses a Button all the the application names where CheckBox is IsSelected() should be stored in a separate ArrayList.

I have tried so many things, but nothing works.
My code is:

main_activity.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.pc.fkidshell.Teen5Activity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Add Selected Apps"
        android:width="170dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</FrameLayout>
```

inflator.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1.7" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Datamodel.java

```
public class Datamodel {
    public String appname = "";
    private boolean selected;

    public String getAppname() {
        return appname;
    }

    public void setAppname(String appname) {
        this.appname = appname;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean isChecked) {
        this.selected = isChecked;
    }

}
```

Adapter.java: (in the CheckBox listener I am using "MyApplication.setMyapps(ss);" to assign the application name to my global class (MyApplication) variable ArrayList  myapps)

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context _ctx;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public ArrayList<Datamodel> data;

    public Adapter(Context c, ArrayList<Datamodel> _arraylist) {
        this._ctx = c;
        this.data = _arraylist;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) _ctx.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflator, parent, false);
        final CheckBox checks = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.b);
        final TextView _setappname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.a);
        checks.setChecked(data.get(position).isSelected());

        Datamodel obj = data.get(position);
        _setappname.setText(obj.getAppname());
        checks.setTag(position);

        checks.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                Datamodel _obj = data.get(getPosition);
                data.get(position).setSelected(isChecked);
                String ss = _obj.getAppname();
                System.out.println("pos is" + getPosition);
                MyApplication.setMyapps(ss);
            }
        });
        return itemView;
    }
}
```

Mainactivity.java:

```
public class Teen5Activity extends Activity
{
    private ListView list;
    ArrayList<Datamodel> res;
    Adapter _adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_teen5);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        List<PackageInfo> _myapps = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0); //all the list of apps pacakage info stores in _myapps
        res = new ArrayList<Datamodel>();   //new arraylist that contains appname and checkboxes status
        for (int i = 0; i < _myapps.size(); i++)
        {
            PackageInfo p = _myapps.get(i);

            Datamodel _model  = new Datamodel();
            _model.setAppname(p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString());
            res.add(_model);
            System.out.println("ajajajja" + res.size() + res.get(i).getAppname());
        }
        _adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), res);
        _adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        list.setAdapter(_adapter);
        Button addbtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add2);
        addbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if((MyApplication.getMyapps())==null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing to ADD!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Added your Apps!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

MyApplication.java:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    private static ArrayList<String> myapps=null;
    public static void setMyapps(String logo)
    {
        myapps.add(logo);
    }
    public static ArrayList<String> getMyapps()
    {
        return myapps;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following mistakes I could find in your code:

1) You need to initialize your MyApplication class's myApps arraylist.If you try to call setMyApps without initializing your arrayList, you will get a null-pointer exception. You need also need a remove method to dynamically update your checked-apps list.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
private static ArrayList<String> myapps= new ArrayList<String>();//Create an instance of the list, don't keep it as null

public static void setMyapps(String logo)
{
    myapps.add(logo);
}
public static ArrayList<String> getMyapps()
{
    return myapps;
}
public static void removeApp(String appName)
{
     myapps.remove(appName);
}

}
```

2) You need to add it to your list, *only* if it is checked, not for the false state. So whenever, you access the list, the elements that are present refer to the *checked* applications.Also, you need to *remove* the app name from the list in the event of a check and a later uncheck case.

```
 checks.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
            Datamodel _obj = data.get(getPosition);
            data.get(position).setSelected(isChecked);
            String ss = _obj.getAppname();
            System.out.println("pos is" + getPosition);
            if(isChecked) //Only if the app is checked
                MyApplication.setMyapps(ss);
            else if(MyApplication.getMyApps().contains(ss))
                MyApplication.removeApp(ss);
        }
    });
```

3)I am not sure why you are extending the MyApplication class from Application here, if your objective is to store the app names.. a simple string arraylist would have sufficed.

4) It would be better to track the applications through their **package name**, instead of app name, as the package name is a more unique property to the app.

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You never check if the checkbox is actually checked, you only ever add items, regardless of if the checkbox is checked or not.

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
{
    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
    Datamodel _obj = data.get(getPosition);
    data.get(position).setSelected(isChecked);
    String ss = _obj.getAppname();
    System.out.println("pos is" + getPosition);
    MyApplication.setMyapps(ss);
}
```

Try something like

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
{
    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
    Datamodel _obj = data.get(getPosition);
    data.get(position).setSelected(isChecked);
    String ss = _obj.getAppname();
    if (isChecked) {
        // TODO: if your apps does not contain 'ss' already {
            MyApplication.setMyapps(ss);
        // }
    } else {
        // TODO: Remove ss from your apps
    }
}
```

You probably could store `List<DataModel>` in your Application instead, if you really wanted, instead of Strings.

You could also use a `Set` object instead of an ArrayList to prevent duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your ArrayList and select the items that have isSelected() as true :

```
ArrayList<String> selectedApps = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Datamodel app : res) {
    if(app.isSelected())
        selectedApps.add(app.getAppname());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Separate Data any string of list and show checkbox checked**
Data come to API response and store to one variable string of list for example:
String socialMode = "Twitter,Instagram,Linkedin,Whatsapp,Facebook"
and given answer just like that
string twit = Twitter;
String insta = Instagram; on words...
then show checkbox checked true.

```
String[] separatedSocialMedia;
private List<String> selectedSocialMediaList = new ArrayList<>();
private CheckBox cbFbS,cbTwitSocial,cbInstagram,cbWhatsapp,cbLinkedIn,cbSnapChat,cbOtherS;
```

get value only english language;
strTwitter = getResStringLanguage(R.string.str_twitter, "en");

```
String socialMedia = Prefs.getString(AUtils.PREFS.SUR_SOCIAL_MEDIA,"");
    if (socialMedia != null && !socialMedia.equals("")){
        separatedSocialMedia = socialMedia.split(",");
        Log.e(TAG, "socialMedia: "+separatedSocialMedia );
        selectedSocialMediaList.clear();
        for (int k =0 ; k<separatedSocialMedia.length; k++){
            selectedSocialMediaList.add(separatedSocialMedia.toString());
            String twit = separatedSocialMedia[k];
            Log.i("social", "socialDataAPI: "+twit);
            String inst = separatedSocialMedia[k];
            Log.i("social", "socialDataAPI: "+inst);
            String fb = separatedSocialMedia[k];
            Log.i("social", "socialDataAPI: "+fb);
            String whats = separatedSocialMedia[k];
            Log.i("social", "socialDataAPI: "+whats);
            String link = separatedSocialMedia[k];
            Log.i("social", "socialDataAPI: "+link);
            String snap = separatedSocialMedia[k];
            Log.i("social", "socialDataAPI: "+snap);
            String other = separatedSocialMedia[k];
            Log.i("social", "socialDataAPI: "+other);

            if (strFaceBook.equals(fb)){
                cbFbS.setChecked(true);
            }else if (strInstagram.equals(inst)){
                cbInstagram.setChecked(true);
            }else if (strLinkedIn.equals(link)){
                cbLinkedIn.setChecked(true);
            }else if (strTwitter.equals(twit)){
                cbTwitSocial.setChecked(true);
            }else if (strWhatsApp.equals(whats)){
                cbWhatsapp.setChecked(true);
            }else if (strSnapChat.equals(snap)){
                cbSnapChat.setChecked(true);
            }else if (strOtherSocial.equals(other)){
                cbOtherS.setChecked(true);
            }

        }
    }
```

get checkbox value in only English value

```
 public String getResStringLanguage(int id, String lang){
    //Get default locale to back it
    Resources res = getResources();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    Locale savedLocale = conf.locale;
    //Retrieve resources from desired locale
    Configuration confAr = getResources().getConfiguration();
    confAr.locale = new Locale(lang);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    Resources resources = new Resources(getResources().getAssets(), metrics, confAr);
    //Get string which you want
    String string = resources.getString(id);
    //Restore default locale
    conf.locale = savedLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, null);
    //return the string that you want
    return string;
}
```